# getActivity getting null in some devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have application that has fragment and on getting some error i want to go to previous fragment So i used

> getActivity().onBackPressed();

Its working fine but in some devices I am getting error.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed()' on a null object reference
   at com.nusatrip.fragment.PaymentProcessFragment.receivedError(PaymentProcessFragment.java:633)
   at com.nusatrip.fragment.PaymentProcessFragment.access$500(PaymentProcessFragment.java:113)
   at com.nusatrip.fragment.PaymentProcessFragment$1.onResponseReceived(PaymentProcessFlightFragment.java:597)
   at com.nusatrip.services.FlightTransactionSubmit.onPostExecute(TransactionSubmit.java:35)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I tried it in my other devices and it's working fine. This error was generated in crashlytics **fabric.io**. 
I don't know why this error of null pointer is coming.

Comment: `getActivity()` may returns `null` in some cases(read documentation when) and in your case it returns `null`... It is connected with Fragment's and Activity's lifecycle

Comment: @Selvin- Like what cases. because most of devices is not facing this issues.

Comment: Obviously when Fragment was detached before AsyncTask finished

Comment: @Selvin but after succesfull call of getActivity().onBackPressed(); only detached will be called right?

Comment: No @Mehdi there are many factors that can destroy your activity. Since your call is asynchronous, there is always a possibility that your activity is already destroyed before getting the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is you are accessing activity in Asynchronous class, and by the time you get your response your Activity might have been already destroyed.

One possible solution is to check for null Activity and perform actions according to that

Another solution that I generally follow is to use a global Context object.

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context mContext) {
    super.onAttach(mContext);
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

//then use this context instead of getActivity() wherever required.
//It makes sure that you have active context object even if object is destroyed.
```

In general this must be avoided as it may cause memory leaks. Ideally you must prefer step-1 of checking the null pointers.

In case you want to follow step-2 (most reliable) make sure you handle the context properly.

**EDIT**

based on your point **on getting some error i want to go to previous fragment So i used**

Here is another thing you can follow,

Create an interface to handle the interaction of fragment with your class

**FragmentChanger.java**

```
public interface FragmentChanger{
    void removeCurrentFragment();
}
```

Then follow the above steps with following changes

```
private FragmentChanger mFragmentChanger;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context mContext) {
    super.onAttach(mContext);
    this.mFragmentChanger = (FragmentChanger) mContext;
}

//and then in your onError method
mFragmentChanger.removeCurrentFragment();
```

and then implement this interface in your activity and perform the changes using fragment manage.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentChanger{
    //other codes
    @Override
    public void removeCurrentFragment(){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        //using onBackpressed is generally not a good idea to go back to previous fragment.
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously second is not a solution for call `onBackPressed` ... after detach such Activity context prolly would be not valid as on 80% the activity was destroyed too ... also it is not *"global Context object"* it is field in some class - non static private fields are not global. Anyway storing context in such way is a terrible idea as it cause context leaks

Comment: Yes @Selvin i already specified about the memory leaks issue involved with having a global context, and just realized there can be a better solution for the task which he is trying. Updated the answer accordingly.